# Flutter RefreshIndicator with FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

I have been looking at how to make a new request to an API using the refresh indicator and then use the data in my app.

I now have the refresh indicator working, only the data is not refreshed while there is new data. I feel that I overlook things or do things wrong. Someone who understands this?

I want to use the refresh indicator with the FutureBuilder but if this does not go together and there is a better way then that is of course also allowed.

I left the code unchanged because the data is grouped. So I have left nothing out which might cause an unclear picture. The data is grouped by date so that I can leave the items under the date using a StickyHeader.

*If the coding is too much and certain things can be removed. Feel free to adjust it :-)*

See picture:
[image]

Code:

```
 // Refresh key!
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
      GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: RefreshIndicator(
            key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
            onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: _meldingen,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data == null) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Loading..."),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    final groupByDates = groupBy(
                        snapshot.data, (obj) => obj.tijd.substring(0, 10));
                    groupByDates.forEach((date, list) {
                      datums.add(date);
                      list.forEach((listItem) {
                        listItem.capcodes.forEach((items) {
                          capcodesList.add({
                            "id": "${items.id}",
                            "gpkr": "${items.gpkr}",
                            "omschrijving": "${items.omschrijving}",
                          });
                        });
                        listItem.voertuigen.forEach((items) {
                          voertuigenList.add({
                            "nummer": "${items.nummer}",
                            "type": "${items.type}",
                            "standplaats": "${items.standplaats}",
                          });
                        });
                        meldingenBijDatum.add({
                          "id": "${listItem.id}",
                          "tijd": "${listItem.tijd}",
                          "melding": "${listItem.melding}",
                          "adres": {
                            "straat": "${listItem.adres.straat}",
                            "plaats": "${listItem.adres.plaats}",
                            "postcode": "${listItem.adres.postcode}",
                            "longitude": "${listItem.adres.longitude}",
                            "latitude": "${listItem.adres.latitude}"
                          },
                          "voertuigen": voertuigenList,
                          "prio": "${listItem.prio}",
                          "capcodes": capcodesList
                        });
                        capcodesList = [];
                        voertuigenList = [];
                      });
                      mapDateMelding[date] = meldingenBijDatum;
                      meldingenBijDatum = [];
                    });
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return StickyHeader(
                            header: Container(
                                height: 50.0,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 16),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Container(
                                          child: Text(
                                              DateFormat.EEEE('nl')
                                                  .format(DateTime.parse(
                                                      datums[index]))
                                                  .toUpperCase(),
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: ThemeColors.brandweer,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                                        Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                                          child: Text(
                                              DateFormat.yMMMMd('nl')
                                                  .format(DateTime.parse(
                                                      datums[index]))
                                                  .toUpperCase(),
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: ThemeColors.brandweer,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10.0,
                                      child: new Center(
                                        child: new Container(
                                          margin:
                                              new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                                                  start: 1.0, end: 15.0),
                                          height: 2.5,
                                          color: Colors.red,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )),
                            content: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                getItemsWidget(datums[index]),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: groupByDates.length,
                    );
                  }
                })));
  }

  Widget getItemsWidget(index) {
    List<Widget> itemsList = new List();
    List namesString = mapDateMelding[index];
    for (var i = 0; i < namesString.length; i++) {
      itemsList.add(GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MeldingPage(
                      id: namesString[i]['id'],
                      tijd: namesString[i]['tijd'],
                      prio: namesString[i]['prio'],
                      melding: namesString[i]['melding'],
                      adres: namesString[i]['adres'],
                      voertuigen: namesString[i]['voertuigen'],
                      capcodes: namesString[i]['capcodes'])));
        },
        child: SingleMeldingItem(
            tijd: namesString[i]['tijd'],
            prio: namesString[i]['prio'],
            melding: namesString[i]['melding'],
            straat: namesString[i]['adres']['straat'],
            plaats: namesString[i]['adres']['plaats']),
      ));
    }
    Column column = new Column(
      children: itemsList,
    );
    return column;
  }

  Future<Null> _handleRefresh() async {

    setState(() {
      _meldingen = Meldingen.getMeldingen();
    });
    
    Completer<Null> completer = new Completer<Null>();
    completer.complete();
    return completer.future;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a StreamBuilder instead of a FutureBuilder. When the Refresh method is called, it should push the new data to the stream that the StreamBuilder uses in the Refresh Widget.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I tried it on your method and it seems to be the ideal solution. Only as soon as I make a request to the api and an existing record has been modified, the StreamBuilder shows, but as soon as an item is added it does not show it ...

Comment: It seems to be going wrong when sorting the dates. This coding is now performed once the screen is loaded. Any idea how I can make that coding global so that it is also called during the refresh? It's about the piece:
```else {
final groupByDates = groupBy(```

Comment: I am not fully sure how you implemented the solution with a stream builder, but whatever you update should be updated by pushing to the stream that the Streambuilder is building off of. On your refresh method handler, it would likely compute the new values and push them to the stream.